# Issues with links under divs

Tags: html, css

Can i do all links on div tree clickable..? I think through all other divs [image: my code]

The middle square is parent... and the columns and left-top square is child... Is there way to make links on all divs(parents,parents-child,child-child and so on) clickable, with no matter of deeps of these divs? `pointer-events: none` just make parent not clickable, and that i don't want.

Comment: Do it with `onclick` not with `href`s

Comment: But in this example, entire div will be clickable? I want just the image. Or u think use onClick on image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution - i just set the z-index of images to highter than divs, and now it works (y)